# Safe area issue with VNDocumentCameraViewController using UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable, vndocumentcameraviewcontroller

How can I extend camera scanning view to safa area while using VNDocumentCameraViewController in UIViewControllerRepresentable?

here is the code

```
struct ScanDocumentView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(recognizedText: $recognizedText, parent: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> VNDocumentCameraViewController {
        let documentViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
        documentViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return documentViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: VNDocumentCameraViewController, context: Context) {
        // nothing to do here
    }
}
```

and here is it's behavior where the bottom safe area is blank
[image: behavior]

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved! just add

```
.ignoresSafeArea()
```

under

```
ScanDocumentView()
```

and that's all

Comment: Thank you! This solved an kind of related issue we had launching a UIKit view controller from SwiftUI with UIViewControllerRepresentable.